# Laravel changing eloquent instance to a builder instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

At least it seems to be doing that.

First I retrieve multiple models:

```
$ConfirmedCards = JobCardHead::where('Status', '=', 'Confirmed')->get();
```

Then I use a for each loop to work on each model:

```
foreach ($ConfirmedCards as $card) {
...
}
```

Now each $card is a collection right? Laravel says that an eloquent model is extends the collection class and if I do,

```
foreach ($ConfirmedCards as $card) {
    echo $card
}
```

I get the data in what definitely looks like a collection. But if I attempt to use the collection method put(), like this

```
foreach ($ConfirmedCards as $card) {
    $card -> put('StartDate', 'someDate');
}
```

I get an error saying that I am trying to call put() on a query\Builder instance, How is $card a builder instance?

Please Help. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your **$card** variable is not a collection but an object extending **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model** class. When you try to **echo** this object, you're seeing it serialized to **JSON**.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how can change it to a collection?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need - how can you turn a single object into a collection of objects?